# jenkins started with all jobs lost, trying to use 'copy existing job' feature

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

the CI server was disconnected for a while for some strange reason from the network and when it came back up, jenkins displayed with no jobs. however in the directory where the jobs live, /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/, the two jobs that should appear are there, but don't show any evidence of existence in the web client.

i tried using the 'copy existing job' and then pointed it to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/existing_test but it tells me: no such job /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/existing_test

any suggestions as to how to get this to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up just building the jobs brand new, wasn't able to find a fix

Answer (score 2):

I know that question can be outdated, but a possible a solution is to run jenkins under appropriate user (the one it run previously). This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

At first I would try and look in the jenkins logs, as your data is in /var/lib/jenkins I would guess your log files are in /var/log/jenkins. Maybe you can find out whats wrong from there.

Also you could try the "load configuration from disk" link in the "manage jenkins" view. That should try to reload the configuration files from your directories, and maybe bring your jobs back. Anyways, you should be able to see something in your logs. If the logs are empty check file permissions, I used to have problems with that after updating sometimes.